# Electric field and magnetic fields interaction

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields

We know that stationary charged particle(produces electric field),when kept under magnetic field,they don't interact(ie no force or deviation).

My question is what if we keep a moving charge (producing $magnetic field$) in an electric field, what will happen i.e any force will act on moving charges or will move without any deviation

If force is applied then how much and will any force will be there on electric field (ie on electrodes between which charge is moving and electric field is produced).

Answer (score 0):

A charge, $q$, stationary or moving, in an electric field, $\vec E$, will experience a force, $q\vec E$ due to that field. If the field is provided by metal plates with a pd between them, the plates (taken as a system) will experience an equal and opposite force.

You draw attention to the magnetic field produced by the moving charge. This will give rise to a 'magnetic force' on other moving or spinning charged particles (e.g. on those in a suitably orientated current-carrying wire or a magnet). If there are no such things nearby, the magnetic field of the moving charge won't cause a force to be exerted.

Comment: A stationary magnetic field from an external source will exert a force on a moving charge, but will not effect a  constant (E) field from an external source.